# Why am I prompted to recover Yoroi Wallet every time on startup?

Tags: wallet, yoroi, recovery

Every time I start the app, despite it logging in, I can not see my wallet.

I can see the two options to add a wallet. After that, I can choose between creating, restoring, and connecting to a ledger.

How can I recover the wallet upon startup?

Comment: Just to double check: have you created a wallet first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure which platform (iOS/Android) you're using or which version of Yoroi wallet. And, I'm a bit confused about the two options. In my Yoroi application (Android, Yoroi v4.0.2, Commit ea5c1120) I see the option to access my wallets (saved) or, at the bottom,

1. ADD WALLET (SHELLY-ERA)
2. ADD WALLET (BYRON-ERA DEPRECATED)

So, if you don't see your wallet(s) listed under (My wallets) then you'll need to either:

- A. CREATE WALLET (which will create a new wallet that will be saved in the application in the future)
- B. RESTORE WALLET (which requires you to have already created a wallet and have your 12/24 word recovery phrase, your private key)
- C. CONNECT TO LEDGER NANO (which requires you to have a Ledger Nano hardware wallet)

You'll need to decide which path makes the most sense for you, but my guess is you'll want to do 1. -> A.

Comment: As you said I will try option A as it is the simplest option here as I am beginner .. but really thanks for great answer ...

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a bug in version v4.0.2 affecting a few users in the way you describe. As a workaround, you can try to restore your wallet again and then delete it. The first wallet should now appear in the initial wallet list screen.

See https://twitter.com/lordb_rocks/status/1384565929665720323